# List strings instead of Count in Model.Tags.Count.ToString() ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I would like to display tags as a list of items rather than a count.

Details.cshtml

```
<div class="display-label">Tags</div>
<div class="display-field">@(Model.Tags == null ? "None" : Model.Tags.Count.ToString())</div>
```

Post.cs

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } 
}
```

Tag.cs

```
public class Tag
{

        public int TagId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // Relationship with Post
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public virtual Post Post { get; set; } // This is new

}
```

I tried List, Ilist, Enumerable in the Details.cshtml view file. I want to display the list of Tags as strings for each post.

Comment: Then you need a loop - `foreach(var tag in Model.Tags) { @Html.DisplayFor(m => tag.Name) }`

Comment: Thanks a bunch it worked! Here's how it ended up happening.

`@foreach (var tag in Model.Tags) 
   {@tag.Name.ToString()}`

Comment: Since the `Name` property is already typeof `string`, there is no need to call `.ToString()` on it :)

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. Did you want to post as the answer and I'll close the question as answered?

Comment: aiapatag has already posted an answer so you can close it out by accepting that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [Foreach](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/razor_cs_loops.asp)

```
<div class="display-label">Tags</div>
    <div class="display-field">@(Model.Tags == null ? "None" : foreach(var item in Model.Tags)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)
}

)
</div>
```